# How to deal with multiple definitions problem and What does symbol type 'W' mean in nm symbol table

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to cross compile C code (involves TFLite) for ARM. I have linked following libraries along with libtensorflow_c.so (removing any one of them gives "undefined references" errors)

- ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
- libc.so.6
- libc++.so
- libdl.so.2
- libm.so.6
- libpthread.so.0
- librt.so.1
- libstdc++.so.6
- libgcc_s.so.1

But I am getting following errors

```
$ make exe 2>&1 | tee log.txt
aarch64-linux-android-clang++ -o NC.exe build/main.o -fPIE -pie -lc -lm -ldl -llog -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -march=armv8-a -nodefaultlibs -lc -lm -ldl -llog -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -march=armv8-a -lgcc  Tlib/libtensorflowlite_c.so Tlib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 Tlib/libc.so.6 Tlib/libc++.so Tlib/libdl.so.2 Tlib/libm.so.6 Tlib/libpthread.so.0 Tlib/librt.so.1 Tlib/libstdc++.so.6 Tlib/libgcc_s.so.1
Tlib/libpthread.so.0:(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of `system'
Tlib/libpthread.so.0:(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of `siglongjmp'
Tlib/libpthread.so.0:(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of `fork'
Tlib/libpthread.so.0:(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of `fcntl'
Tlib/libpthread.so.0:(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of `longjmp'
clang60++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [exe] Error 1
```

I checked symbol tables of .so files and 'system' appears in libc.so.6 and libpthread.so.0 with symbol types 'W' and 'T' respectively.

```
>>nm -D libpthread.so.0 | grep "system"
U __libc_system
000000000001107c T system
>>nm -D libc.so.6 | grep "system"
000000000003bccc T __libc_system
00000000000d7418 T svcerr_systemerr
000000000003bccc W system
```

It is similar for rest of the words. My question is what does "W" mean as a symbol type and how to get rid of this multiple definition problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order of linking the libraries solved these errors. (libpthread should be placed before libc)

Thanks